# Unable to hide Toolbar while scrolling RecyclerView, possible cause?

Tags: android, xml, android-recyclerview, android-coordinatorlayout

I am trying to hide the `ToolBar` as the `RecyclerView` gets scrolled, however, `ToolBar` doesn't hide or move at all. This is how I implemented it:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="@dimen/margin_8"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/appbar">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/list_toolbar_side_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/list_toolbar_side_margin"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/titleText"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:gravity="start|center"
            android:textSize="19sp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    >


        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/homeTeamRView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/list_side_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/list_side_margin"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/margin_16" />

</FrameLayout>
```

How to fix ?

Comment: `app:layout_scrollFlags` should be in `AppBarLayout`. Do you enough content to scroll?

Comment: yes, 20 images, in linear order for recycler view, enough for scroll I believe

Comment: @Blackbelt tried in `AppBarLayout` doesn't work as well!

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue please add in `Toolbar` widget (`android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar`):

```
 app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
       />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_eez_dine_home" />
```

As like above